# Firebase setValue not working in IOS 10, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, exc-bad-access

My app is crashing when I try to save a comment to Firebase. This code was working perfectly before the Xcode 8 update:

```
    func saveNewComment(){

    //get date
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.day,.month,.year], from: date)

    let year = components.year
    let month = components.month
    let day = components.day

    //format month
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let months = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols
    let monthSymbol = months?[month!-1]
    let todaysDate = "\(day) \(monthSymbol),\(year)"

    //trim comment
    let comment = textView.text
    let trimmedComment = comment?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    //save new comment
    let commentRef = ref.child("Stores").child(getRef!).child("CommentArray").childByAutoId()

    commentRef.setValue([

        "Comment": trimmedComment,
        "Date": todaysDate

    ])

    self.delegate?.commentSubmitted(true)//delegate
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)//dismiss view

}
```

Apparently the error is when i try to use "setValue" to set those key value pairs. Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What update did you perform? And what error are you getting?

Comment: What is getRef?

Comment: So I updated the question, my bad, I meant the Xcode 8 update. Also getRef is just the reference to the node as you wrote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firebase` does not accept an `optional` type as a value

```
let trimmedComment = comment?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Try to unwrap `trimmedComment` and `todaysDate` value with `!`

```
commentRef.setValue([
        "Comment": trimmedComment!,
        "Date": todaysDate!
 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `getRef!` is a proper node name, And then change the **todaysDate** to

```
let todaysDate = "\(day!) \(monthSymbol!),\(year!)"
```